# Invoking .Net webservices from Java

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I have a web service created in .Net and I am interested in invoking this web service in my java application.

What set of libraries would be the best suited to do this? I've looked into GlassFish, but have been unable to find anything examples of this being used to invoke a .Net web service, only creating the Java side web service.

I have some experience using wsif, but it appears to be rather outdated and would like to use something more current if possible.

Comment: are .net services using soap? do you have a wsdl? i'm not familiar with .net, but if they have a wsdl, using java to access a soap-based service it's trivial and googable.

Comment: yes they have. The whole concept of Web Services hinges around the fact that, if you're using Java, you don't need to know what's going on with the .Net code if you have access to the interface which tells the inputs and outputs of a service. So, just google how to access web services in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out those links:

[Your question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1213244.aspx)

[WebServices in java](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/edujini_webservice_java.aspx),
this tutorial uses JAX-WS 2.0

[A simpler approach to what you want](http://www.slideshare.net/junyuo/access-net-web-services-from-java)

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Web services stack in Java is JAX-WS, which is the one included in Glassfish, and it can be downloaded from http://jax-ws.java.net/. There are other JAX-WS compliant implementations out there, but not necessarily using JAXB (the one used by JAX-WS).

Use the JAX-WS wsimport utility to generate the Java client side from a WSDL.